# Adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand intuition behind this.

From my script.

**Adjoint operator**. Let $A\in L(V,W)$. Now, for every linear functional $g\in W'=L(W,K)$ we define linear functional by $$v \mapsto g(Av),\quad \forall v\in V$$

We can easily prove that we defined **linear** functional on $V$. We will call this functional as $f=A'g$

---

There is more, but I don't understand what does this have to do with adjoint operators? Can somebody explain me how this works?

Comment: I didn't post all of it, just introduction, $A' \in L(W',V')$ from above is adjoint operator in final chapter.

Comment: Also, $f(v)=(A'g)(v)=g(Av), \forall v \in V$

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I have in my book. I understand that this is mathematics manipulation, and it turns out, it is adjoint operator with all wanted properties. But how did someone think about defining it this way

Comment: Yea, and I think the key here is that we can only write $f(v)=(A'g)(v)=g(Av), \forall v\in V$ and we can't rewrite this as $f(v)=A'(g(v))...$ because $A'$ maps $W'$ to $V'$, I think usually when we have composition of linear operators we can switch brackets